# How to enable the spi to connect the 3.5inch rpi-display using yocto

Tags: yocto

I have generated a image for raspberrypi3 board using yocto, now I'm trying to connect the 3.5inch RPI LCD (A) V3 XPT2046 Touch Controller.
I'm unable to find the ".dts" file in yocto for rpi3
I enabled the all spi supports which are in menuconfig
and I didn't find spi support to enable in yocto

Comment: The dts files are part of the kernel source. The yocto repos only carry some specific modifications. You can find the RPi3 trees in `$KERNEL_SRC_ROOT/arch/arm64/boot/dts/broadcom` folder